# Parse PHP SDK version requirement

Tags: php, parsing, ubuntu, sdk

I don't see it anywhere in the documentation or ReadMe but what is the PHP version requirements for the Parse PHP SDK?

I am running PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.22, this is a Virtual Machine running Ubuntu.   And I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /vagrant/www_root/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php on line 317
```

I guess the Parse SDK requires PHP 5.4 with support for short array syntax.

Comment: Can you show that line of code?

Comment: Sure here is the line of code that is not compiling:
  if (!is_array($value)) {
>>      $value = [$value];
    }

Answer (score 0):

That error is definitely a version issue. That code requires requires PHP 5.4+ but you are running PHP 5.3.

But you can fix this but changing that code to:

```
if (!is_array($value)) { 
    $value = array($value); 
}
```